# Missing OpenGL extension items when compiling VTK for iOS

Tags: ios, vtk

I'm trying to compile VTK 7.1.0 for iOS, as per the instructions at https://blog.kitware.com/building-vtk-for-mobile-architectures/.

I'm seeing the following issue:

```
 [ 90%] Built target vtkglew [ 90%] Building CXX object
 Rendering/OpenGL2/CMakeFiles/vtkRenderingOpenGL2.dir/vtkOpenGLPolyDataMapper.cxx.o

/Users/nclex/Documents/dev/VTK/VTK-7.1.0/Rendering/OpenGL2/vtkOpenGLPolyDataMapper.cxx:1582:36: error: 

      use of undeclared identifier 'GL_MULTISAMPLE'

  bool multisampling = glIsEnabled(GL_MULTISAMPLE) == GL_TRUE;
```

GL_MULTISAMPLE is defined in glew.h which is part of the source tree, but not sure why it's not being seen during compilation.

I'm using Xcode 8.1 on MacOS 10.12.1 (Sierra). The VTK code is the 7.1.0 link located at http://www.vtk.org/download/.

Comment: Hello @occulus, I am trying to use VTK in my iOS project, I get this error in their example 'vtkActor.h' file not found.  I see that vtk framework is not there. Could you please guide me where to download the proper demo ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there's a few mistakes in `vtkOpenGLPolyDataMapper.cxx`.

To fix compilation, I've replaced:

```
#if GL_ES_VERSION_3_0 != 1
  bool multisampling = glIsEnabled(GL_MULTISAMPLE) == GL_TRUE;
#else
  bool multisample = false;
#endif
```

with

```
#if GL_ES_VERSION_3_0 != 1 && defined GL_MULTISAMPLE
  bool multisampling = glIsEnabled(GL_MULTISAMPLE) == GL_TRUE;
#else
  bool multisampling = false;
#endif
```

**UPDATE**
The git repo was updated the same day with fixes for this.
The repo for this project doesn't seem to be very well curated (or at least, pull requests aren't tested across the board before being merged in).